# Time synchronization in Unity3D

Tags: node.js, unity-game-engine, client-server, photon

I'm developing the fps game with the client-server architecture. The client is built using Unity3d and the server is based on NodeJs. I'm thinking about the best way of synchronization of the time between server and the client. I found this solution [link](https://github.com/arasmussen/Socket.io-time-sync). I wonder if it works really good, in comparison of using photon server .

Comment: How do you plan on using time? The question is too vague.

Comment: @Kimimaru, I'm  using time for calculating the time of message delivery between client and server like here: http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/NetworkMessageInfo-timestamp.html

Comment: I would give the library you linked a go, seeing as it does what you're looking for. If you're not comfortable integrating it into your main project yet I would set up a test project to see how you like it. It's hard to state how well something will work for someone or not because it's dependent on each project. Naturally, libraries will be easier to integrate into some projects and harder in others.